# Why does rebasing onto an ancestor cause a merge conflict

Tags: git, git-svn

I am using git-svn. I tried to do a git svn rebase. Everything broke. I found the old state of the repo in the reflog and tried to progress in the safest way possible. Now my repo looks like this:

**Update: I did a merge before rebase**

```
... -- A (origin/branchA) -- B -- C -- D (BranchA,HEAD)
                                 /
                                /
... -- E (origin/trunk,Trunk) -- ...
```

I did the following

```
branch BranchA-Fix origin/branchA
```

The repo looks like this

```
... -- A (origin/branchA,BranchA-Fix) -- B -- C -- D (BranchA,HEAD)
                                _____________/
                               /
   -- E (origin/trunk,Trunk) -- ...
```

Then I try to move my work to the side so that I don't get any conflicts trying to do a git svn rebase

```
git rebase BranchA-Fix
```

> First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it... Applying:
>   Its script minor update Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...

...

> merge... Auto-merging hardware/d3_script.ii CONFLICT (content): Merge
>   conflict in hardware/d3_script.ii Failed to merge in the changes.
>   Patch failed at 0001 Its script minor update The copy of the patch
>   that failed is found in:
>   /cygdrive/SOME_DIRECTORY/.git/rebase-apply/patch
>
> When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue". If
>   you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead. To
>   check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase
>   --abort".

What happened? Why on earth would rebasing onto a direct ancestor cause any kind of merge conflict? How do I progress with svn update without causing merge errors?

Answer (score 1):

This conflict is very much expected and represent a well known issue of intermixing  merges and rebases. Particularly acute with git-svn.

Basically you are asking git to replay on top of the `BranchA-Fix` all the commits that lead to you current HEAD (at `BranchA`) but not to `BranchA-Fix`. Which effectively means the whole trunk form the very beginning, among the rest.

You can see this visually by `git log HEAD --not BranchA-Fix` or, even more explanatory to your case - try and repeat your rebase in interactive mode: `git rebase --interactive BranchA-Fix`

In general for git-svn with bidirectional syncs it is strongly advised to avoid merges and fully switch to the rebase workflow. Reason - rebase nature of `git svn dcommit`.

The solution to your current situation depends on the details of the relations of the branches, necessity to keep history (non-squashed commits) of the git-only branches and ability to rebase branches (the last in your case seems to be no problem).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution (aside from avoiding merging entirely) is to use a mixed reset instead of a rebase.

Basically, instead of running:

```
git rebase BranchA-Fix
```

You can instead do:

```
git reset BranchA-Fix
[... stage changes for B...]
git commit -m "B"
[... stage changes for C and E...]
git commit -m "E"
[... stage changes for D...]
git commit -m "D"
```

...Or, more usefully, if you were planning to squash them anyway:

```
git reset BranchA-Fix
git commit -am "MyNewMessage"
```